# Actual mechanics of Maven dependency resolution?

Tags: maven

I believe I understand the concept behind dependency management in Maven, and I have seen it work so flawlessly.  However, I am not sure how this gets resolved in practice.  For example, if I show a dependency with a groupId of `org.apache.httpcomponents`, how does Maven know where to download the corresponding artifact from, if it is not available locally?

And if I create an artifact locally, and give it a nice URIish groupId, how does Maven know that artifact does not need to be downloaded from anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven caches all external artifacts in its local repository and also puts all interally built artifacts into the local repository. This is the first place to look.

Artifacts not present there, or those which need an update and drawn from the configured external repositories. If nothing is configured, MavenCentral is used.